# Latex: how to check if figures are on the same page of call out/text?

Tags: latex

If a figure is mentioned in a text, say page 10, but the corresponding figure appears on page 11, how can I automatically introduce some additional text (e.g.: on page 11) beside the figure mention in the text.

Instead of doing this:
`Figure \ref{fig:test} on page \pageref{fig:test} shows bla bla.`

Autocheck:
`Figure \\ref{fig:test} \check shows bla bla.`

Where `\check` is a macro to check the co-existence of the figure referencing and figure (float), whether they are on the same page. If true, return `Null`, else return `on page \pageref{fig:test}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `varioref` and `cleveref` packages. This will automatically add the appropriate text or page number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{content...}
\label{key}
\end{figure}

\vref{key} 

\clearpage

\vref{key}

\clearpage

\vref{key}

\end{document}
```